# Populate HTML dropdown from text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with hard-coded values:

```
<select name="value" id="value">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

I would like to load a text file to populate the values. The text file will have each value on a new line.

values.txt

```
A
B
C
D
```

I've tried this:

```
<select>
    <?php
    if ($file = @fopen('values.txt', 'r')) {
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
            echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
</select>
```

But there are no choices on the dropdown when I do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may not have permission to read the file. I copied and pasted your code and it works fine. If you're on a unix system you can do `sudo chmod 744 values.txt`

Comment: Get rid of **@** fopen, so that you can see error if any. Use only `fopen()`

Comment: @ksealey I'm running on Windows 7. Later on in the program, I have javascript code that reads a .csv file just fine, so I don't think it could be a permissions issue. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @Rohit I got rid of the `@`, but did not notice any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array element of the list

```
$filename = 'values.txt';
$eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//create an array
echo '<select name="value" id="value">';
foreach($eachlines as $lines){
    echo "<option>{$lines}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I tried your code just now, but still, the dropdown menu wasn't populated with anything... :(

Comment: @CdSdw give the full path to the file name.

Comment: The curly brackets syntax won't work with single quotes.

Comment: @Midas Thanks a lot and sorry to CdSdw for single quotes

Comment: Hmm I think it might be my newbie-ness at HTML, but when I create a new HTML file with `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body>(your code)</body></html>`, the only thing displayed on the screen when I open the HTML file is the literal text `"; foreach($eachlines as $lines){ echo "{$lines}"; } echo ""; ?>`...I'm not sure why the echoes are being displayed literally. I changed all of the single quotes to double quotes to be safe.

Comment: @CdSdw beacuse your file extension is not PHP ! in html you cannot use PHP tags